# Configure Rails force ssl on staging

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, devise, staging

My client requires HSTS use on his website. He provided me with ssl certificates for the domain he owns.

Recently I set up the staging server (it runs under production env configuration) and here's where problems with devise begun. "The change you wanted was rejected." is the message I receive every time I want to login. To my mind it happens for force_ssl option turned on production mode. I don't want to generate ssl certificates for the staging server just to testing purposes.

How do you guys deal with that?

Comment: How do you have the staging server configured?  Is there a web server in front, if so you could terminate the certificate at the web server and proxy in rails requests.

Comment: @vee yeah I got an nginx server in front of unicorn on staging. But I haven't got you comment: "terminate the certificate"? I have 2 different EC2 instances: one for staging and one for production. Do you mean handle all requests for staging and production from one nginx server?

Comment: by terminate the certificate, I meant to have `nginx` in your case, deal with the certificate.  Following is what I found as I do not have much experience in nginx with unicorn: http://kvz.io/blog/2010/09/21/ruby-with-nginx-on-ubuntu-lucid/, and this: https://coderwall.com/p/sw-vhw